# Compiling Boost asio on cygwin occurs many errors

Tags: c++, boost

I train official Boost asio example([timer.cpp](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer1/src.html)) on cygwin. And I want to compile it without creating any `.lib` or `.dll` and minimize dependencies for distributing by open-source. But when I copy only `asio` and `config` directories and `asio.hpp` and `config.hpp` files into `libs` directory(According the official manual, Boost asio requires only Boost config. Refer to [Boost asio dependencies](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/using.html#boost_asio.using.dependencies)), and compile the example with `g++ timer.cpp -Ilibs -o timer`, An error that there's no `boost/version.hpp` occurs.

And I copy the omitted header and compile it... Similar error occurs again. And copy... occurs... copy... occurs... It's no end. So I copy all Boost libraries into `libs`, and compile it. But I confused many and many errors and warnings occurs. Despite I declare `#define __USE_W32_SOCKETS` and `#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0603` (I'm working on Windows 8.1) before `#include <boost/asio.hpp>`. Following is final compile outputs. I'm getting tired.

```
In file included from /usr/include/w32api/winsock2.h:56:0,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/socket_types.hpp:38,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/impl/winsock_init.ipp:22,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/winsock_init.hpp:125,
                 from libs/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:28,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from libs/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from src/main.cpp:4:
/usr/include/w32api/psdk_inc/_fd_types.h:100:2: warning: #warning "fd_set and     associated macros have been defined in sys/types.      This can cause runtime     problems with W32 sockets" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "fd_set and associated macros have been defined in sys/types.  \
  ^
In file included from libs/boost/asio/detail/impl/posix_tss_ptr.ipp:24:0,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/posix_tss_ptr.hpp:76,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/tss_ptr.hpp:27,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/call_stack.hpp:20,
                 from libs/boost/asio/impl/handler_alloc_hook.ipp:19,
                 from libs/boost/asio/handler_alloc_hook.hpp:80,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/handler_alloc_helpers.hpp:21,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/bind_handler.hpp:19,
                 from libs/boost/asio/detail/wrapped_handler.hpp:18,
                 from libs/boost/asio/io_service.hpp:24,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_io_object.hpp:19,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_socket.hpp:20,
                 from libs/boost/asio/basic_datagram_socket.hpp:20,
                 from libs/boost/asio.hpp:21,
                 from src/main.cpp:4:
libs/boost/asio/error.hpp:87:31: error: a function call cannot appear in     a constant-expression
           BOOST_ASIO_NATIVE_ERROR(ERROR_BROKEN_PIPE),
```

**Summary:**

Q1. Boost asio requires some other Boost libraries not only Boost config, but not all (I guess). How to check library dependencies of Boost asio?

Q2. On cygwin, Compiling timer example of Boost asio with g++ occurs many and many errors and warnings. But I'm according to official manual. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Comment: You shouldn't mess around with Boost installation. Why not simply follow the tutorial and specify exactly which library you want to compile (if any) ?

Comment: @Chnossos For cross-platform. If I compile Boost with 'b2' on Windows, and I use got several `.lib` or `.dll` files, it works on Windows only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Boost Getting Started](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/more/getting_started/windows.html) guide, [Boost.Timer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/libs/timer/index.html) **must** be built, and users fecthing your code will need to install boost as well (your code or project mustn't worry about how boost is installed, juste indicate that it is needed).

You can use the static version to reduce external dependencies.
I've never done it with Cygwin but with MinGW, it should be equivalent.

Go into boost root directory, open a cmd.exe.

Your `bin/` folder containing the compiler executables must be in your path. If it is not, type this first:

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;<path to your cygwin bin folder here>
```

Now type:

```
bootstrap gcc
```

Then, when `bootstrap` has finished:

```
b2 toolset=gcc variant=debug,release link=static threading=multi
```